# For a quadratic extension $E/K$, condition on a character $\chi:E^\times/E^{\times 2} \to C_2$ to give a $C_4$-extension $L/K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, local-fields

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_2$, and let $E/K$ be a quadratic extension. By local class field theory, quadratic extensions $L/E$ correspond to quadratic characters $\chi:E^\times \to C_2$. Of course, quadratic extensions $L/E$ also correspond to elements of $E^\times / E^{\times 2}$, where $\alpha \in E^{\times} / E^{\times 2}$ corresponds to $E(\sqrt{\alpha})$.

It is well-known that $E(\sqrt{\alpha})$ is a $C_4$-extension of $K$ if and only if $N_{E/K}(\alpha) \in dK^{\times 2}$, where $E = K(\sqrt{d})$. I would like a condition on $\chi:E^\times \to C_2$ for the corresponding quadratic extension $L/E$ to be a $C_4$-extension of $K$.

One approach would be to make the correspondence $\chi \leftrightarrow L \leftrightarrow \alpha$ explicit, and then translate the norm condition on $\alpha$ into a statement about $\chi$. The $L\leftrightarrow$ correspondence is already quite explicit, but I'm not sure about $\chi \leftrightarrow L$. I imagine what I'm looking for is some sort of "explicit reciprocity law", but I'm not sure what I'm looking for or what form that should take. Moreover, I suspect that such a correspondence would probably not be readily compatible with the norm condition on $\alpha$.